# How to freeze part of selected layer(eg nn.Linear()) of a model in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

question:
fc = nn.Linear(n,3);
I want to freeze the parameters of the third output of the fc when I train this layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @PlainRavioli , it's not possible yet and you can set the gradient to zero so the current weights do not change.
But you have to do this after calling `loss.backward()` and before calling `optimizer.step()`.

So being `fc = nn.Linear(n,3)`, for freezing the parameters of the third output:

```
loss.backward()
fc.weight.grad[2,:] = torch.zeros_like(fc.weight.grad[2,:])
fc.bias.grad[2] = torch.zeros_like(fc.bias.grad[2])
optimizer.step()
```

Calling `loss.backward()` computes `dloss/dx` and do  `x.grad += dloss/dx`. So before this operation, gradients are set to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

With monolithic layer you can't. But you can split layer, making a separate `Linear` for each output channel:

```
fc1 = nn.Linear(n,1)
fc2 = nn.Linear(n,1)
fc3 = nn.Linear(n,1)
```

Here you can freeze `fc3`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible yet, however the common solution is to set the gradient to zero before backpropagation so the current weights do not change.

With `param` the parameter of your layer you want to freeze:

```
param.grad[2,:] = torch.zeros_like(param.grad[2,:])
```

before calling `loss.backward()`

Don't forget to set to zero the adequate bias gradient also !

Make sure the weights you are targetting did not change afterwards

Comment: but there has a bug: If i do it the way you say, before calling loss.backward(), actually，loss.grad is NoneType.`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I believe this is because you did not pass any input through your network, so the gradients are not defined yet. Can you try passing an input, then do this, then do `backward()` ?

Comment: I have passed an input to the model,still  no grad.`para.grad` output `None` . And i checked the `requires_grad=True`